# Vectorising a nested loop with AVX2

Tags: c, sse, avx, avx2

I am trying to vectorise the inner loop the following nested loop. Firstly, is this good practice, or should one avoid attempting to vectorise nested loops?

The following works, it has already some basic loop unrolling.

```
int sparsemv(struct mesh *A, const double * const x, double * const y) {

  const int nrow = (const int) A->local_nrow;
  int j = 0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  #pragma omp parallel for private(j, sum)
  for (int i=0; i< nrow; i++) {
    sum = 0.0;
    const double * const cur_vals = (const double * const) A->ptr_to_vals_in_row[i];
    const int * const cur_inds = (const int * const) A->ptr_to_inds_in_row[i];
    const int cur_nnz = (const int) A->nnz_in_row[i];
    int unroll = (cur_nnz/4)*4;
    for (j=0; j< unroll; j+=4) {
      sum += cur_vals[j] * x[cur_inds[j]];
      sum += cur_vals[j+1] * x[cur_inds[j+1]];
      sum += cur_vals[j+2] * x[cur_inds[j+2]];
      sum += cur_vals[j+3] * x[cur_inds[j+3]];
    }
    for (; j < cur_nnz; j++) {
      sum += cur_vals[j] * x[cur_inds[j]];
    }
    y[i] = sum;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to vectorise using 256-bit Vector registers in AVX2, I get either the incorrect answers or seg faults. x and y are aligned but A is not, but for the moment, all loading and storing is done using unaligned operations since that is the only time I don't get seg faults:

```
int sparsemv(struct mesh *A, const double * const x, double * const y) {

  const int nrow = (const int) A->local_nrow;
  int j = 0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  #pragma omp parallel for private(j, sum)
  for (int i=0; i< nrow; i++) {
    sum = 0.0;
    const double * const cur_vals = (const double * const) A->ptr_to_vals_in_row[i];
    const int * const cur_inds = (const int * const) A->ptr_to_inds_in_row[i];
    const int cur_nnz = (const int) A->nnz_in_row[i];
    int unroll = (cur_nnz/4)*4;
    __m256d sumVec = _mm256_set1_pd(sum);
    for (j=0; j< unroll; j+=4) {
      __m256d cur_valsVec = _mm256_loadu_pd(cur_vals + j);
      __m256d xVec = _mm256_loadu_pd(x + cur_inds[j]);
      sumVec = _mm256_add_pd(sumVec, _mm256_mul_pd(cur_valsVec, xVec));
    }
    _mm256_storeu_pd(y + i, sumVec);  // Is this storing in y + i + 1, 2 and 3 aswell?
    for (; j < cur_nnz; j++) {
      sum += cur_vals[j] * x[cur_inds[j]];
    }
    y[i] += sum;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a gathered load for x[cur_inds[j]]

Comment: @PaulR what would that look like? I am not familiar with gathered loads

Comment: Search for `gather` in Intel's intrinsics finder like Paul hinted you should: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html&text=gather&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2

Comment: This should work (previous comment was mixing `float` with `double`): `__m256d xVec = _mm256_i32gather_pd(x, _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i)(cur_inds + j)), 8);` -- still untested, though.

Comment: @chtz I get the following error: ```error: can’t convert value to a vector
       __m256d xVec = _mm256_i32gather_pd(x, _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i)(cur_inds + j)), 8);```

Comment: Try `(__m128i const*)` instead of `(__m128i)` (as I said, I did not test this, mostly because you did not provide a [mre] I could start with ...)

Comment: @chtz Thank you, it compiles, however still produces the wrong answer :/ I can't really give a mre as it would be pretty big. But thank you for the help anyway. I'll just keep trying.

Comment: Instead of storing `sumVec` to `y+i` you need to do a horizontal reduction (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction).